# How to create a big title which works on big and on small screens as well?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive

I'm working on a webpage main title. I want to set a `100%` height background image and a big title on the front of it.

This is how I did:

In the CSS file:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url("../img/image.JPG");
  height: 100%;

  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;    
}

.bigtitle {
     /**    padding-left:15%;***/ 
        padding-top: 20%;

color: white; 
font-family: 'Trocchi', serif; 
font-size: 1500%; 
font-weight: normal; 
margin: 0;

/*line-height: 1.0em;*/
}
```

In HTML file:

```
<div class="bg">
    <center><h1 class="bigtitle">My title</h1></center>
</div>
```

I also tried to set the size of the title with `em` but it was the same problem.

This is good on the desktop but completely fail on mobile or small screen size. How can do to work on mobile and on desktop as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just leave this as a comment but I don’t have permissions yet:
You can manually adjust the size of the title to your liking for different screen sizes using media queries in your css. Although they probably aren’t the most efficient way to add responsiveness, they have worked wonders for me.

Comment: Media queries allow you to set exactly what size you want your title to be at any specific screen size. For example, on a phone screen, you can make the text size smaller so it doesn’t go off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try using this, I have no problem with it, you can set your desired height, should work on both mobile and desktop.

```
.bg {
  background-image: url("../img/image.JPG");
  height: calc(100vh);
  width: auto;

  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;    
}
```

Comment: this makes the background very well, but the text on it, is still sticking out from the background image on small screen, and is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Take off the height, then your image will equal the background-size: cover;

```
.bg {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bw7xmytp/

Comment: This is true, but the text on it is still unreadable on small screens.